# "There is still an eternity left before we can be together." or "There is still an eternity before we can be together."?

Tags: grammar

Is the word *left* really necessary?

Saying *There is still a computer to fix before we're finished with the job* is grammatically correct english, isn't it? As well as saying *There is still a computer left to fix before we're finished with the job*, right? Is it just a matter of how it sounds?

Comment: As to the two examples in the text of your post: they can have different meanings, and will usually be interpreted differently. The meaning that they will be understood to have will depend on the context in which they are used.

Answer (score 1):

"Left" implies that some progress has already been made. If you say:

> There's still a computer left to fix before we're finished with the job.

it implies that you've already done some part of the job. If you say:

> There's still an eternity left before we can be together.

it implies that some time has already passed.

Answer (score 0):

In your example:

> There is still a computer (left) to fix before we're finished with the job.

*left* is implied so I don't think it matters if you use it or not.

However regarding the examples in your title, only this one is OK as is:

> There is still an eternity **left** before we can be together.

Eternity as used is relative to the present time, and since you are pointing to the future (before we can be together), we are only concerned with the "eternity" between now and when "we can be together". This is indicated with "left".

Using just "eternity" by itself could also refer to past times, which is not the case here.

Meaning the use of *left* (or not) in such a phrase is context dependent.

Comment: I never would have used "left" in this sentence.  The past vs future aspect of eternity is clear through the word "still" and the context of the sentence.